# Trying to upload a video to YouTube, the video uploaded but I'm getting an exception after it's uploaded

Tags: c#, youtube-api, google-data-api

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.Extensions.MediaRss;
using Google.GData.YouTube;
using Google.YouTube;



namespace YoutubeTesting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        YouTubeRequestSettings settings;
        YouTubeRequest request;
        string devkey = "AI39si6xhSQXx95FTYIACWPfq-lLIphblgaReuz9z6VEjR1Q6YjrV6FRN2U6FN6P6-lGF2OYaUZhCVOKJ_MCk4o6kPeUszvf5A";
        string username = "tbout72";
        string password = "password here";


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("You Manager", devkey, username, password);
                request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
                Video video = new Video();
                video.Title = "test";
                video.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Comedy", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
                video.Keywords = "Comedy";
                video.Private = false;
                video.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("d:\\P9170031.MOV", "video/MOV");
                request.Upload(video);
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Uploaded");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have referenced some dll files from  http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list
I downloaded two files: Google_Data_API_Setup_1.9.0.0.msi  Google Data API Setup (1.9)  and YouTube_SDK_1.9.0.0.msi

Now I tried it to upload a video file again this video file and it uploaded well, no problems once and the video is working on youtube.com
But even if it's working in my code I got an exception error. Whether the upload is working or not, I'm getting the exception.

1. The program is running and hanging for a few minutes, I can't see form1 while it's running.
2. After a few minutes I'm getting the exception.

Even though I'm getting the exception and I'm getting it each time the program is working the file is uploaded well.

I don't know why but I see the file is uploaded like 3-5 times and once or twice it was uploaded well the same file the others are rejected since it's a duplicate. But I ran the program once so why sometimes it's uploading the file so many times at once? Now I tried again; the program isn't running any more, I closed it like 10 minutes ago. And saw the file uploaded and being processing now after it finished the process I see the file uploaded again, and now it's rejected since it's a duplicate. But why is it keeping uploading the file if the program isn't running?

The time between the uploads is like 14 minutes same file my program is closed I didn't run it anymore and yet I see two files with same name, same file: one is ok one is rejected for duplication.

So I have 3 problems now:

1. Can't see form1 while running the program like the program is hanging.
2. Exception error all the time appears.
3. The file is uploading more then once.

The exception is on the line: request.Upload(video);

The exception error message is: Execution of request failed:

```
https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads
```

This is the full exception:

```
Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException was caught
  Message=Execution of request failed: https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads
  Source=Google.GData.Client
  StackTrace:
       at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
       at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
       at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
       at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
       at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
       at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute()
       at Google.GData.Client.MediaService.EntrySend(Uri feedUri, AtomBase baseEntry, GDataRequestType type, AsyncSendData data)
       at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert(Uri feedUri, AtomEntry newEntry, AsyncSendData data)
       at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert[TEntry](Uri feedUri, TEntry entry)
       at Google.GData.YouTube.YouTubeService.Upload(String userName, YouTubeEntry entry)
       at Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequest.Upload(String userName, Video v)
       at Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequest.Upload(Video v)
       at YoutubeTesting.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\C-Sharp\Youtube_Testing\YoutubeTesting\YoutubeTesting\Form1.cs:line 47
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message=The operation has timed out
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
       InnerException:
```

line 47 on form1.cs is: request.Upload(video);

Now again I see that it was uploading the file like 4 times:
Can't figure out why and how it's keeping uploading the file.
And 3 of the files are rejected for duplicate, one is ok!

I asked someone and he told me it's working for him without any problems.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 pro .net 4.0
Windows 7 64bit.

I checked my YouTube log in and password many times and also in my Gmail and all the time same problems and exception.

Answer (score 3):

The exception states what is going on here: Your request timed out. You can alter the timeout with [this property](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r902/docs/folder54/P_Google_GData_Client_RequestSettings_Timeout.htm). It is set to 100,000 milliseconds by default. You can set it to a larger number, to increase the timeout or to -1 to stick to the default of HTPPRequestObject:

```
settings.Timeout = -1;
```

Also, you should upload the video in a seperate thread. This way, the GUI stays responsive and does not 'hang', like you say.

**Update:**

You can start a Thread like this:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    var settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("You Manager", devkey, username, password)
    {
        Timeout = -1
    };
    var request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
    var video = new Video()
    {
        Title = "test",
        Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Comedy", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema)),
        Keywords = "Comedy",
        Private = false,
        MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("d:\\P9170031.MOV", "video/MOV"),
    };
    request.Upload(video);
})).Start();
```

Comment: Can you show me how ot use the thread on my code ? Couldnt find how.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Tutorial to upload YouTube Video via c#.

Refer Here : http://codewithgeek.blogspot.com/2015/12/upload-video-to-youtube-from-c-aspnet.html